# How to run python, java, php, nodejs,ruby applications on same vps?

Tags: python, ruby, node.js, apache, nginx

How to run python(Django,Flask), Java(spring),PHP, Nodejs(express),Ruby(rails) application on same VPS.
If it is possible on VPS, can we do similar on Reseller Hosting where we have SSH Access.

> I have readed on some other Articles they.. suggests to Use "Virtual Host" in Apache.
>   Also which one is better NGINX or Apache for same..?

Comment: You can use Docker

Answer (score 2):

This is depends on what do you want to achieve.

If you want to run separate applications on the same VPS you can just:

1. Install all required packages on this VPS
2. Deploy your applications (via standard deployment or via docker)
3. Prepare config for web-server, for example Nginx.

In nginx you can achive it pretty easily:
Just put a file inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` for each application.
Each of this files will look something like this:

```
upstream rails_application {
 server unix:/home/deploy/rails_application/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
   listen 80; # application port
   server_name example.com; # application host

   location / {
     proxy_pass rails_application;
   }
}
```

Then you will also need to put  all neccessary config for each application there.

Then, about Apache vs Nginx. It also depends :) I prefer using Nginx, cause it is fast and  powerful.

And one last point: consider automatisation.
There are two places for automatisation:

1. Preparing VPS - you can do it manually or use Chef, for example. It will give you possibility to easily add new application, or move your code to new VPS.
2. Deploying application - using things like Capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

Just add '&' in the end of your command.Like

```
python manage.py runserver &
```

Then when you close the ssh session, jobs still running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Any user can run any service on a VPS. Just make sure that you are not conflicting with available ports in your services.